# Theatrhythm Final Fantasy: Curtain Call, why do they smile?

Tags: theatrhythm-curtain-call

When beginning a song, we see the face of all the member of the team. From time to time, some of them smile or have a non-standard face (Zak with heart for eyes, Ramza with shining eyes...).

I ve first thought it was because I was playing a song from a game they appear in, but Zak had nonstandart face on FFIII songs, so it must not be that.

What do cause thoses non-standard face?

Comment: I suspect it's just random. Kinda like the random phrases they had in the previous game...